Why is it YHWH and not 'HYH?
I've been approaching the bible from how people "discovered" this belief. Arguably, Exodus 3:14 is the origin:

And God said unto Moses, I AM THAT I AM: and he said, Thus shalt thou say unto the children of Israel, I AM hath sent me unto you.

In the original text, this verse says “אֶהְיֶה” (ehyeh / 'HYH), commonly translated as “I am” and “I will be.”
But why does the rest of the bible say YHWH then (which is the third person singular for the same verb of "to be" in Hebrew)? It seems like Moses, when writing down his divine experience initially, misinterpreted the entire thing and erroneously shifted from first person singular ('HYH) to third person singular (YHWH), and everyone else just went with it, despite God clearly telling him that "he" actually wants to be addressed as "I am"?

Welcome to the group. You've asked a good question. (not an easy accomplishment for new contributors!) Do read the Tour and the FAQ when you get a chance, as there are are number of pitfalls that you did not stumble into this time.

"the third person singular for the same verb of "to be" in Hebrew" — So is it simply a matter of God's referring to himself as "I AM", and everyone else's referring to him as "HE IS"?

@RayButterworth Yeah, at least that's how I understand it as well. I mean, of course God can't really "refer" to himself, as only humans can actually write down words. So when humans would call God "I AM", I guess this semantically "merges" the consciousness of the reader and the divine consciousness of God? It's kind of the transition from monotheism (in the exclusive sense of "God is external") to monism (in the universal sense of "unity with God"). But surely many other people before me had the same thought already?

The Hebrew word אֶֽהְיֶ֖ה in Ex 3:14, translated "I AM" is transliterated as: 'ehyeh.
Note that the aleph letter א is not equivalent to the English "A" but is a glottal stop and hence usually transliterated as ' .  Thus, if one wanted to merely transliterate the consonants only (ie, ignoring the pointed vowels below the letters) then the correct transliteration of אֶֽהְיֶ֖ה would be 'HYH.
Now to the other of the OP's question:
The name sacred name, or "tetragrammaton" used more than 6000 times in the OT is יְהוָֹה = "YHWH", eg, Gen 2:4, 5, 7, 8, etc.  It is commonly understood to be part of the verb to be and according to Strong's lexicon:

Derived from the Hebrew verb הָיָה (hayah), meaning "to be" or "to
exist."

Thus, both אֶֽהְיֶ֖ה and יְהוָֹה are very closely related.
The title/name "I AM" may have appeared in the OT according to the Septuagint in several places such as Deut 32:39, Isa 41:4, 43:10, 13, 25, 45:19, 46:4, 48:12, 51:12, 52:6.

+1 ... so the real question becomes "how to YHWH come to be translated as I AM"?

Thanks for the answer and for the correction regarding the aleph! I was also wondering this for a fundamental reason: If God must actually be referred to as "I", doesn't this mean that the divine is internal, coming from within each believer, instead of an external, "personal" God?

And does someone know if there have ever been re-translations of the bible where it just says "I am/I will be" instead of "Lord" and "I" instead of "He", so that the reader can identify with the divine actions?

@sigalor - the very first translation of the Bible did this - the Septuagint in 250 BC.

@DanFefferman - I am unaware that YHWH is ever translated (or even should be translated) "I AM".   אֶֽהְיֶ֖ה and יְהוָֹה are very closely related but not the same word.

@Dottard Interesting, I didn't even know about the Septuagint version yet! Seems like there it's translated as "ὁ ὤν" (ho ōn) = "the One who is", where "ὁ" is the masculine singular definite article and "ὤν" is the present active participle of the verb εἰμί (eimi, "to be"). So there it's neither "I" nor "he", but more like a title transcending any separation of identities? Seems like that's closer to Plotinus' "the One"?

@DanFefferman Regarding your first question: No, it's not really a translation thing, but more fundamental. After all, in Exodus 3:14, God tells Moses that God wants to be referred to as "I AM". So the question is rather: Why did Moses still write the rest of his book referring to God as "HE IS" (YHWH) instead of "I AM"?

@sigalor I say, "I am Ron."  You say, "He is Ron."

@sigalor a better example might be "I think, therefore I am" and "he thinks, therefore he is".

Moses doesn't seem to be taking אֶהְיֶה אֲשֶׁר אֶהְיֶה as a name, to be repeated verbatim, but more as a title. For an analogy, one might address a king as "Your Majesty", but describe him to someone else as "His Majesty"; "Your Majesty" isn't meant to be repeated exactly word for word, but adjusted grammatically to fit the surrounding context.
The yodh at the beginning is almost certainly a third person singular masculine prefix, so while He refers to Himself as "I, who exist", Moses repeats it to the people as "He, who exists". See Brown-Driver-Briggs for some more discussion of the grammar—some have argued that it instead means something like "He, who creates", but the verbal form isn't really in question.
You might also notice that the root used doesn't quite line up, היה (HYH) vs הוה (HWH). This is an archaic root that means basically the same thing, but had mostly fallen out of use by the time of composition.

Good point, so interesting how Moses seems to have made that interpretation to take this as a title (where grammatical adjustments are thinkable/"allowed" at all) instead of a literal name!

This makes what happened in John 8:58–59 much more understandable.  They didn't want to kill Jesus simply because he spoke aloud the name of God, it was because he said it in a way that only God himself would use.

I don't know if it's just me or not, but I think everyone is forgetting verse 15... They ALWAYS forget verse 15... HE gave HIS "SHEM"(Name).
Exodus 3:15

And Elohim says again to Moses, “Thus you say to the sons of Israel:
YHWH, Elohim of your fathers, Elohim of Abraham, Elohim of Isaac, and Elohim of
Jacob, has sent me to you; this [is] My Name for all time, and this
[is] My memorial, to generation [and] generation.


this [is] My Name for all time

The Name of the Creator of Heaven and Earth is YHWH, YAHWEH being closest approximation. This is confirmed in Exodus that it is YHWH, not "HYH"(pronounced haw-yah). "HYH" ends with "YAH", interestingly enough the contracted form of YHWH, which is one reason the linguists know it's pronounced like "YAH". The Covenant made with Israel was with YHWH.
Exodus 20:2

“I [am] your Elohim YHWH, who has brought you out of the land of
Egypt, out of a house of servants.

We all know "1961. hayah" means "to be" or "to exist". When The Son said this in John 8:58, "ego emimi", HE was identifying as this Voice/Logos(John 1:1-2) who spoke to Moses, the Voice who spoke to the Israelites from the Mountain... Yes, the very same who who gave HIS Name, YHWH(John 5:43, Joel 2:32).

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
